# Ansible : get playbook result

Tags: notifications, ansible

I am using Ansible to deploy a PHP website into my servers (production, staging, etc), and I would like to get a notification (via skype). 
For it I need learn ansible to send post request (with some params) when any ansible task starts or finishes (with result : success/failed or with error description)

Help me please with realization of all this stuff since I have any ideas about it. =(

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own callback plugin.

Take a look at [slack](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.3/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py) notification plugin.